# How to read data and read user response to each line of data both from stdin

Tags: bash, stdin, interaction

Using bash I want to read over a list of lines and ask the user if the script should process each line as it is read. Since both the lines and the user's response come from stdin how does one coordinate the file handles? After much searching and trial & error I came up with the example

```
exec 4<&0
seq 1 10 | while read number
do
    read -u 4 -p "$number?" confirmation
    echo "$number $confirmation"
done
```

Here we are using exec to reopen stdin on file handle 4, reading the sequence of numbers from the piped stdin, and getting the user's response on file handle 4. This seems like too much work. Is this the correct way of solving this problem? If not, what is the better way? Thanks.

Comment: You might consider explaining more how it happens that "both the lines and the user's response come from stdin".  This smells like a strange way to do business...

Comment: From the user's perspective the command needs to run like "rm -i *". (The blog posting about the script is at [killmatching](http://calliopesounds.blogspot.com/2012/08/a-less-violent-killmatching.html).) That the script needs to use a pipeline internally is not exposed to the user. And the script should not inconvenienced the user by this need.

Comment: I've read your blog post and you totally want to separate the internal stdin from the user's stdin.  This means using two passes.  Luckily with your app there are no performance concerns.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could just force `read` to take its input from the terminal, instead of the more abstract standard input:

```
while read number
do
    < /dev/tty read -p "$number?" confirmation
    echo "$number $confirmation"
done
```

The drawback is that you can't automate acceptance (by reading from a pipe connected to `yes`, for example).

Comment: Is `/dev/tty` in the POSIX standard now?

Comment: It's listed in [section 10.1 of IEEE Std 1003.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap10.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using an additional file descriptor is a right way to solve this problem. Pipes can only connect one command's standard output (file descriptor 1) to another command's standard input (file descriptor 1). So when you're parsing the output of a command, if you need to obtain input from some other source, that other source has to be given by a file name or a file descriptor.

I would write this a little differently, making the redirection local to the loop, but it isn't a big deal:

```
seq 1 10 | while read number
do
    read -u 4 -p "$number?" confirmation
    echo "$number $confirmation"
done 4<&0
```

With a shell other than bash, in the absence of a `-u` option to `read`, you can use a redirection:

```
printf "%s? " "$number"; read confirmation <&4
```

You may be interested in [other examples of using file descriptor reassignment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18899/when-would-you-use-an-additional-file-descriptor).

Another method, as [pointed out by chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11935042), is to read from a named file, namely `/dev/tty`, which is the terminal that the program is running in. This makes for a simpler script but has the drawback that you can't easily feed confirmation data to the script manually.

Answer (score 0):

For your application, [killmatching](http://calliopesounds.blogspot.com/2012/08/a-less-violent-killmatching.html), two passes is totally the right way to go.

- In the first pass you can read all the matching processes into an array.  The number will be small (dozens typically, tens of thousands at most) so there are no efficiency issues.   The code will look something like

  ```
  set -A candidates
  ps | grep | while read thing do candidates+=("$thing"); done
  ```

  (Syntactic details may be wrong; my bash is rusty.)
- The second pass will loop through the `candidates` array and do the interaction.

Also, if it's available on your platform, you might want to look into `pgrep`.  It's not ideal, but it may save you a few forks, which cost more than all the array lookups in the world.

Comment: Reading it all into an array could use a lot of memory and delay processing if the input is large (I think `seq 1 10` is just a place holder, or he could just iterate over that directly with `for number in $(seq 1 10)`.

Comment: @chepner Hello?  It's a shell script.  If performance is that much of a concern, the shell is probably not the right tool for this job.

Comment: Suppose the input is essentially infinite (a log file streamed from a continuously running process, for example). Don't assume you can wait for the end of the input to begin processing if you don't have to. The user explicitly said "the script should process each line as it is read".

Comment: @chepner agreed, but then it makes no sense to say that the user's responses are also interleaved on stdin.  How on earth is that supposed to be accomplished?  I think we need some clarification from OP.